# Change all prices in MySql database wordpress e-commerce

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm preparing for new currency in my country. How I can easily divide all prices from 3.45.
All prices stored in mysql table wp_postmeta _wps_price. I haven't found any wordpress plugins which will convert all.

Comment: Are you using phpmyadmin or do you have access to the shell?

Comment: I'm using only phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all products and change price with wp queries.
My example:

```
$get_your_products = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'wpsc-product',
    'showposts' => -1
) );

foreach( $get_your_products as $product ){
    $current_price  = get_post_meta($product->ID, '_wps_price', true);
    $new_price      = $current_price / (3.45);
    update_post_meta($product->ID, '_wps_price', $new_price);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta_wps_price SET price = price / 3.45
```

This will divide all your prices by 3.45. You need to change price to whatever your column that stores the prices.

Answer (score 0):

My question was with mistake. With edited Micheal's code I succeeded. Also find out how to round result.

```
   UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value`= `meta_value` / 3.45 WHERE meta_key='_wpsc_price'
   UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value`= round(meta_value,2) WHERE meta_key='_wpsc_price'
```

I hope this will help somebody. Today I learned MySql basic's.